# toggling one directive effects other dircetive inside ngrepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wrote an angularjs directive to show and hide ajax spinners. The visibility of the spinner is toggled by show and hide buttons whose functionality is written inside the MainController. There is a variable inside the controller which is set to true and false based on the button click. This variable is passed to the directive using isolate scope. When I try to toggle one spinner, all the other spinners are also visible. How can I change my code to only toggle the particular spinner.

https://plnkr.co/edit/AFmBVbHaBPk66T7UjPC5?p=preview

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module('app',[])
  .controller('MainController',[MainController])
  .directive('loadingDirective',[loadingDirective]);
  function MainController(){
    var mc = this;
    mc.showMe = showMe;
    mc.hideMe = hideMe;
    mc.loading = false;
    function showMe(){
      mc.loading = true;
    }
    function hideMe(){
      mc.loading = false;
    }
  }
  function loadingDirective() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:true,
        scope:{
          loading:"=loading"
        },
        template: '<span class="spinner">Loading…</span>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
              scope.$watch('loading', function (val) {
                
                  if (val)
                      $(element).show();
                  else
                      $(element).hide();
              });
        }
      };
  }
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.spinner {
  position: relative;
  /* [1] */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  /* [2] */
  height: 1em;
  /* [2] */
  font-size: 32px;
  /* [3] */
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  /* [4] */
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* [5] */
  text-indent: 100%;
  /* [5] */
  -webkit-animation: 0.5s spinner linear infinite;
  animation: 0.5s spinner linear infinite;
  /**
   * 1. Make the spinner a circle.
   */
  /**
   * The (optically) non-spinning part of the spinner.
   *
   * 1. Border around entire element fills in the rest of the ring.
   * 2. Paler than the part that appears to spin.
   */
}
.spinner, .spinner:after {
  border-radius: 100%;
  /* [1] */
}
.spinner:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid;
  /* [1] */
  opacity: 0.5;
  /* [2] */
}

/**
 * Size variants (built by adjusting `font-size`).
 */
.spinner--small {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.spinner--large {
  font-size: 64px;
}

/**
 * Color overrides.
 */
.spinner--light {
  color: #fff;
}

.spinner--dark {
  color: #333;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spinner {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div ng-controller="MainController as mc">
      <div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5]">
        <loading-directive loading="mc.loading"></loading-directive>
        <button ng-click="mc.showMe()">show</button>
        <button ng-click="mc.hideMe()">hide</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: [Icycool](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5039495/icycool) answer is more suitable for my problem as I need to control the toggling of the spinner, before and after an ajax call, to signify loading. However the solution provided by [Nivedit](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5002305/nivedit) is very generic and can be used in many situations. Thanks so much for the help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the spinners to have their own states, then they should be controlled by different variables.

In your example it is achievable by using an array to hold the variables

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5]">
    <loading-directive loading="mc.loading[i]"></loading-directive>
    <button ng-click="mc.show(i)">show</button>
    <button ng-click="mc.hide(i)">hide</button>
</div>

mc.loading = {};
function show(i){
  mc.loading[i] = true;
}
function hide(i){
  mc.loading[i] = false;
}
```

In a more real case example where you have some data and you use `ng-repeat` over them, you should assign the loading states inside the elements themselves.

This is a common technique to assign state to each items in `ng-repeat`

```
mc.fruits = [
    {name:"apple"},
    {name:"orange"},
    {name:"starfruit"}
]

function load(fruit) { fruit.loading = true; }
function noLoad(fruit) { fruit.loading = false; }

<div ng-repeat="fruit in mc.fruits">
    <loading-directive loading="fruit.loading"></loading-directive>
    {{fruit.name}}
    <button ng-click="mc.load(fruit)">show</button>
    <button ng-click="mc.noLoad(fruit)">hide</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `loading` variable watched is common for all the directives used, hence when the model is changed the watch condition runs 5 times in your case, removing all the spinners.

I used the `index` to see what is being hidden or shown,

Updated fiddle: https://plnkr.co/edit/Jjfk6v7TJZHlQicM45ln?p=preview

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5]">
    <loading-directive data-index="{{$index}}" loading="mc.loading" offset="mc.offset"></loading-directive>
    <button ng-click="mc.showMe($index)">show</button>
    <button ng-click="mc.hideMe($index)">hide</button>
  </div>
```

Angular

```
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('MainController',[MainController])
.directive('loadingDirective',[loadingDirective]);
function MainController(){
var mc = this;
mc.showMe = showMe;
mc.hideMe = hideMe;
mc.loading = false;
mc.offset =-1;
function showMe(offset){
  mc.loading = true;
  mc.offset = offset;
}
function hideMe(offset){
  mc.loading = false;
  mc.offset = offset;
  console.log(offset);
}
}
function loadingDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace:true,
    scope:{
      loading:"=loading",
      offset:"=offset"
    },
    template: '<span class="spinner">Loading…</span>',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {


          scope.$watch('[loading, offset]'  , function (val) {

            if(attr.index == scope.offset || scope.offset == -1){
              if (val[0])
                  element.show();
              else
                  element.hide();
            }
          });
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SCRIPT:

  function showMe(i){
  mc.loading = true;
  i=true;
  }
```

IN HTML ADD THIS

```
  <div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5]">
 <span><loading-directive loading="mc.loading" ng-show="i==true"></loading-directive>
    <button ng-click="mc.showMe(i)">show</button></span>
    <button ng-click="mc.hideMe()">hide</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Working Plunkr:** https://plnkr.co/edit/peGDxYJzKJgiHuPp4zmQ

You needed to define the isolated scope in the directive correctly. Essentially, your directive was still dependent on the controller as you were using the same variable `mc.loading` to determine the state of all directive instances.

By moving the deterministic variable `$scope.loading` as well as the buttons inside the directive, we are completely isolating each directive instance and making them all completely independent units.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="MainController as mc">
  <div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5]">
    <loading-directive></loading-directive>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('app',[])
  .controller('MainController',[MainController])
  .directive('loadingDirective',[loadingDirective]);
  function MainController(){
  }
  function loadingDirective() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:true,
        scope:{},
        template: '<div><span ng-if="loading" class="spinner">Loading…</span>' 
        + '<button ng-click="showMe()">show</button>' 
        + '<button ng-click="hideMe()">hide</button></div>',
        controller: function($scope) {
              $scope.showMe = showMe;
              $scope.hideMe = hideMe;
              function showMe(){
                $scope.loading = true;
              }
              function hideMe(){
                $scope.loading = false;
              }
        }
      };
  }
```